# How to revert symlink from /var/tmp to /tmp

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-httpd, webserver

I created a symlink from `/var/tmp` to `/tmp` folder but this seems to create issues with Apache `PrivateTmp=true` using `/var/tmp` folder.

How can I fully revert the below commands and restore the same privileges to `/var/tmp`?

```
sudo mv /var/tmp /var/tmpold
sudo ln -s /tmp /var/tmp
sudo cp -prf /var/tmpold/* /tmp/
sudo rm -rf /var/tmpold/
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with something like the following:

```
sudo rm -f /var/tmp
sudo mkdir /var/tmp
sudo chown root:root /var/tmp
sudo chmod 1777 /var/tmp
```

Just as a note, you don't generally want to symlink system directories like this.  Programs often make assumptions that they are, in fact, directories, and you'll find that various things don't work, and most maintainers will be unsympathetic to you doing this.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to have done the job!